# Strange fancybox behavior

Tags: fancybox

Faced the following problem.
There is a link. When you click on it, a form with checkboxes appears.

By default, checkboxes are all in the unckecked position - that is, not selected

It is necessary that when the user closes the pop-up window, so that these checkboxes, when reopened, are in the state in which they are at the time of page loading.

That is, if at the very first click, the fancybox-window opens, and all checkboxes are not checked, and then the user noted, for example, 2 of 3, changed his mind, and closed the window with 2 checked boxes, and then opened the window again so that the checkboxes were all are unchecked again, that is, as if the user visited the page for the first time.

Here's an example:: [code](https://jsfiddle.net/fenix_63/kLanz10q/13/)

```
<body>
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fancyapps/ui/dist/fancybox.css"
/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fancyapps/ui/dist/fancybox.umd.js"></script>

<div id="form" style="display:none;">
  <input type="checkbox" name="check_1"/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check_2" checked/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check_3"/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check_4"/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="check_5"/>
</div>

<a class="fancybox" href="#form" data-fancybox>Open Modal</a>
</body>
```

I made it so that by default only the 2nd checkbox from the top is marked. It is necessary that if the user marks more checkboxes, or marks everything at all, or removes everything, then when he closes the window, and reopens it, so that there is the initial state of the form.

Because on a real project, for some reason, fancybox seems to "save" the state of the form, and when you reopen this pop-up window, the data is no longer default, although the user closed the window, and, as it were, "changed his mind" with his choice.

Help please, can anyone come across this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That is NOT "strange behavior", that is, in fact, one of the major features of Fancybox - to display DOM element and to put back at original place after closing. Therefore all user-made changes stay there after closing.

If you wish to not preserve changes, you can display a cloned element, simply add `data-type="clone"` to your link.